# Using Filter operator in Reactor Java

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am trying to filter out the name which are  not present in DB results. It's not working

> Data Present in Db:

```
  A,B,C,D
```

Payload Contains:

```
C,D,E,X
```

Expected Result:

```
E,X
```

Below is the code snippet.

```
     public void filterName(Flux<String> payloadList)
          {
           nameRepo.findAll() <-- DB call which is reactiverepository
           .map(dbObj->dbObj.getName())                
           .collectList().flatMapMany(Mono::just)
           .map(dbNameList->payloadList.filter(name-> 
           !dbNameList.contains(name)).subscribe())
          .subscribe(z-> System.out.println(z));;   
    }
```

> In result I am getting LambdaSubscriber object.

Comment: Saying "it's not working" is not a helpful description of a problem. We need to know what you expect to happen, what actually does happen and what errors, if any, are produced along the way

Comment: Your example is using Reactor, not RxJava.

Comment: Did my answer help you? or do you want me to add something to my answer? otherwise, feel free to accept my answer if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `collectList` returns a `Mono<List<String>>` that can be transformed to `Flux`.
Therefore, using `flatMapMany` it becomes `payloadList` filtering out the `dbNameList`.

```java
public void filterName(Flux<String> payloadList) {
    nameRepo.findAll() < --DB call which is reactive repository
        .map(dbObj -> dbObj.getName())
        .collectList()
        .flatMapMany(dbNameList -> payloadList.filter(name -> !dbNameList.contains(name)))
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
}
```